# Best practices for sharing resources between multiple AWS cdks?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am new to AWS CDK but essentially I have a UI service in lambda and api gateway and another service in ECS. Both services have their own CDK but need to use the same Dynamo table. Is it possible to share the same dynamodb resource between 2 CDKs? Is there a best practice around this? Should we exclude Dynamo from our stacks?

Comment: When you say “ Both services have their own CDK“, do you mean different stacks in the same repo or are these in completely different repos?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar use case, and I simply use the Cloudformation Output, to share the Table ARN.

e.g.

In StackA, I have the Dynamodb Table

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { Table, AttributeType, BillingMode } from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';
export class StackA extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const table = new Table(this, 'my-table', {
      partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: AttributeType.STRING },
      billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
      tableName: 'mytable'
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'my-table-output', {
      value: table.tableArn,
      description: 'Data Storage',
      exportName: this.stackName + '-tablearn'
    });
  }
}
```

In StackB

```js
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { Table } from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';
export class StackB extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const stackATable = Table.fromTableArn(this, "stackA-table", cdk.Fn.importValue("StackA-tablearn"));
  }
}
```

Comment: will it not cause problem as  stack A cannot be updated independently as stack B is now dependent on it?

Comment: Update should not be a problem, only when trying to delete StackA, Cloudformation will stop you because StackB depend on it.